# MySql multiple GROUP BY alternative

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I have two tables: `teams` and `messages`

```
teams
========
id | name


messages
============================
id | team_id | created_date
```

I need a result set that looks like this:

```
team name  |  number of messages  | most recent message
```

For example:

```
Joe Blow's Group   |   23   |   2018-08-29
```

My initial try at this:

```
select team.id, team.name, count(messages.team_id) as 'Number of 
Messages', messages.created_date as 'Last Message' from messages inner join 
teams on messages.team_id = team.id group by team.name
```

Produced:

```
Joe Blow's Team   |   23   |   2018-02-14
Bob's Team   |   12   |   2018-04-15
```

etc etc

The issue is that the dates are of the oldest message created for that team, not the most recent. If I try to add `sort by` it only sorts this result set but the wrong dates. If I try multiple 'group by' I get a row for every message.

Does this need a subquery or is there a simpler way to have the `created_date` be the most recent?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What's not MCVE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MAX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_max.asp) function to get the latest `created_date`.

```
SELECT group.id, 
       group.name, 
       COUNT(messages.group_id) AS 'Number of Messages', 
       MAX(messages.created_date) AS 'Last Message' 
FROM messages 
INNER JOIN groups ON messages.group_id = group.id 
GROUP BY group.name
```